# Sklearn metrics in groupby function with attribute error for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe df:

```
      A           B         type        month model forecast_value actual_value
0  71022         ETF      backtest        4   Arima   10              11
1  71022         ETF      backtest        5   Arima   10              11
2  71022         ETF      backtest        4   MA      20              11
3  71023         ADC      backtest        4   Arima   5               10
4  71024         DAC      backtest        4   Arima   8               20
...
```

How can I use the `groupby`and a `sklearn.metrics` without getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'actual_value'

When I run the following command:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'model'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x.actual_value, x.forecast_value)).reset_index()
```

The desired output would be:

```
A      B     model   mean_squared_error
71022  ETF   Arima     2
71022  ETF   MA        81
71023  ADC   Arima     25
71024  DAC   Arima    144
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, you cannot use `agg` as it's using independent Series only, you need [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
out = (df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'model'], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x.actual_value, x.forecast_value))
      )
```

*NB. `reset_index` is also not needed.*

Output:

```
       A    B  model   None
0  71022  ETF  Arima    1.0
1  71022  ETF     MA   81.0
2  71023  ADC  Arima   25.0
3  71024  DAC  Arima  144.0
```

Comment: how can I avoid the column name 'none' ?

Comment: Using named aggregation with a dictionary?